# Bootstrap Dropdown Button Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have just started playing around with bootstrap, and when I try to fallow the example per Getbootstrap's component page the button doesn't want to work as advertised. I have seen and now tried a number of different solutions to this problem which has me thinking that I maybe over thinking what is wrong here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rubish</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="maindev1.0.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbardev1.0.0.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar-header pull-right">
<button id="menubutton" class="btn btn-default btn-md dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
type="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> </button>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">yadayada</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">yadayada</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">yadayada</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">yadayada</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">yadayada</a>
    </li>

</ul>


</body>

</html>
```

I can get the button to show up and it looks like its active when I click it but it can not get the drop down to appear. I have tried it with Safari, Chrome, and Firefox with the same result in all three. Is there something that I am forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if it is in a navbar or just a normal one. From your code it looks like you are trying top do it in a navbar. I also included a normal dropdown button.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8607/

```
<!-- Normal Single Dropdown button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct I am trying to put this button in the nav bar. I will add that code to original post if you think that's where the error is.

Comment: see my fiddle, it is in a navbar. You may need to expand the panel with the buttons

Comment: Okay, wow I think I need to go back and reread that stuff. I miss understood where I thought that they were all the same button. Thank you for pointing this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

```css
select {background-color: blue; color: white; border: 2px solid; border-radius: 6px;}
```

```html
<select name="yada">
<option value="yada">yada</option>
<option value="yada">yada</option>
<option value="yada">yada</option>
<option value="yada">yada</option>
</select>
```

Why not just replace the button with a dropdown like this and then style it to look like a button?